# Why "xterm -display localhost:0.0" fails

Tags: xorg

When running

```
xterm -display localhost:0.0
```

I get the following error:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
```

I get the same error if I substitute 127.0.0.1 for localhost

but `xterm -display :0.0` works fine. Does anyone knows what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because TCP connection to the X server is disabled by default (instead, your local session connects via the Unix sockets mechanism).

You can enable TCP connections in systems that use the lightdm display manager by editing the `[SeatDefaults]` section of the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and adding

```
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

The equivalent in GDM is supposedly

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

(I have not verified this, since I'm using lightdm).

*Please note that this is probably disabled with good reason, since it represents a possible attack vector: I'd suggest using SSH with X forwarding instead if you need remote access to an X server.*

Comment: Ok now it is working if I use localhost. I sill have the same error if I use the local IP address. i.e. "xterm -display 192.168.1.8:0.0"

Comment: You may need to add it to the xhost access list e.g. `xhost +192.168.1.8` - see `man xhost`